# Total Friend Count in Twitter API 1.1 version

Tags: twitter

Is there a [Twitter API version 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1) call that would provide the total number of friends a user is following?

The [GET Friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids) is the closest I found, however, it provides a list of all a user friend ids, not a total amount.

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi&count=5000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you use the `users/show` endpoint of the v1.1 API you can retrieve information about a particular user.

One of the fields that is returned is called `friends_count` - this is the value you are looking for.

Full details here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show

Comment: No problem - glad that that was helpful.

Comment: Just to addon: `/users/lookup.json` endpoint for bulk user query

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is the right answer and if you want to try a better way you can use as follows:

this is [twarc](https://twarc-project.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for python that is helpful for hydrating ids from tweeter API.

> twarc is a command line tool and Python library for archiving Twitter JSON data. Each tweet is represented as a JSON object that is exactly what was returned from the Twitter API.

for using this library in python you can simply write the code below in a python file.

```
from twarc import Twarc

t = Twarc(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token,access_token_secret)
for tweet in t.hydrate(open('ids.txt')):
  print(tweet["text"])
```

the consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret comes from (https://developer.twitter.com/apps) in your tweeter developer account.

*This is for bulk user-ids that saved in ids.txt file that separated by enter ("\n")*